# Prevent CPU caching?

Tags: c++, caching, cpu

Is there any high-level way (i.e. not assembly) to prevent data that you know will only be used once (or once in a long while) from polluting the cache?  Assume that restructuring the code won't help.  If not,  then in theory is this something compilers could readily implement?

Comment: the keyword `volatile` can have that side effect (at the compiler level). Do you want to avoid cache pollution at the CPU cache?

Comment: Yes, I want to avoid polluting the CPU cache

Comment: I don't think there's a direct way of controlling the CPU cache as the MMU will always want to read large blocks of memory (usually L1 cache size worth of memory around the access) to amortize costs of accessing DRAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The C++ standard does not even acknowledge the existence of caches.